# Book file not starting from page 1

Tags: page-numbering

I need to write a Latex (Book Class) text, that, instead of starting from page 1, would start from page 101. This means that the second page will have number 102, ecc.
Is there a way? Someone could help me

Thanks

Comment: `\setcounter{page}{number}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Put `\setcounter{page}{101}` somewhere in your preamble.